# Error with XKCD comic scraping program

Tags: python, python-3.x

Following the "Automate the boring stuff" book, I've written a script to download every xkcd comic. I've followed the code from the book exactly(as far as I can tell), but I'm receiving an error I don't understand.
[Link](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/) 
Traceback:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/ericdusseau/PycharmProjects/AutomateTheBoringStuff/downloadXkcd.py
Downloading page http://xkcd,com...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x104f80240>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 649, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 376, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xkcd,com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x104f80240>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ericdusseau/PycharmProjects/AutomateTheBoringStuff/downloadXkcd.py", line 11, in <module>
    res = requests.get(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xkcd,com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x104f80240>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

SourceCode:

```
#! python3
# downloadXKCD.py - Downloads every single XKCD comic.

import requests, os, bs4

url = 'http://xkcd,com'             #starting url
os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)  # store comics in ./xkcd
while not url.endswith('#'):
    #Download the page
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

    #Find the URL of the comic image.
    comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
    if comicElem == []:
        print('Could not find comic image.')
    else:
        try:
            comicUrl = 'http:' + comicElem[0].get('src')
            #Download the image.
            print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
            res = requests.get(comicUrl)
            res.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
            #Skip this comic
            prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
            url = 'http://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')
            continue


    #Save the image to ./xkcd
    imageFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
    for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        imageFile.write(chunk)
    imageFile.close()


    #Get the Prev button's url.
    prevLink = soup.select('a[rel="prev"]')[0]
    url = 'htt[://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')

print('Done.')
```

Comment: `url = 'http://xkcd,com'`  That should be `.com`, not `,com`

Comment: I can see several redefinition of the base url. Moreover, at the bottom of your code, your url seems malformed: `htt[://`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output gives you an idea where the problem lies:

```
Downloading page http://xkcd,com...
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

`http://xkcd,com` is an invalid URL. It should be `.com`, not `,com`.

---

Speaking of incorrect URLs, you also have another invalid one later in your code:

```
url = 'htt[://xkcd.com' + prevLink.get('href')
          ^ Should be 'p'
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes to the code in "Automate the boring .." book and dont see issues even if there are no images 
 try:
        elem = requests.get('https://xkcd.com/')
        elem.raise_for_status()
   except Exception as esc:
        print('exception in search:%s' %(esc))

elemSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(elem.text,'html.parser')

elemSouplink = elemSoup.select('.comicNav a')
  # print('elements:'+str(elemSouplink))

while (not (elemSouplink[1].get('href')=='/1/')):

```
   prev= elemSouplink[1].get('href')
  # print('prev:'+str(prev))
   elem=requests.get('https://xkcd.com'+prev)
  # print('new link:https://xkcd.com'+prev)
   elemSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(elem.text,'html.parser')
   elemSouplink = elemSoup.select('.comicNav a')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma in `xkcd,com`. Not a dot...

Answer (score 0):

There is a git repository having a script that downloads a random xkcd comic image and set that image as a wallpaper. You can set that in cron for every minute so that it will change the desktop wallpaper:

[xkcd_random_wallpaper](https://github.com/anandtripathi5/random-xkcd-wallpaper)